# jQuery DataTables - Handling special characters

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using [datatable](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js) library to display the results.
I am facing issue while searching the results.
For instance, when I put the 'e' character, I'd like to search every word only with 'e'.
I do not want words containing 'ê' or 'é', 'è'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search.regex potion as true, and that will help you, I already tested and works for me, I test u, and ú.

[image]

[image]

```
"search": {
            "regex": true
        }
```

Add that to your Datatables options. Hope it works for you.

Source: https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.regex